# What rough spots or omissions in the GAE docs tripyou up or cost you time?

Tags: google-app-engine

If you could wave the magic wand and fix something in the GAE 1.5.5 documentation that have caused you lost time, grief, or missed opportunities, what would they be?

Comment: I think this topic is interesting, but not a good stackoverflow question. There is no "right answer" to this question.  At the very least it should be a community wiki.

Comment: Also, "one thing" would be a better question than "three things" - that way people can vote up individual answers. @PeterRecore CW doesn't really exist anymore.

Comment: Reworded. The context for the question is a chance to move workarounds upstream, into the docs.

Comment: So one thing that I didn't know about for a long time, until Nick mentioned it in a solution, was the ability to use path components as parameters.  It seems like a pretty important piece of functionality and I still can't seem find it in the webapp documentation.

Comment: I find it an interesting and useful question; thanks for asking!

Comment: @Dave hey Dave, thank to have marked my answer as accepted but..what does it mean? Are you going to fill the gap of the documentation :)?

Comment: The gnomes have been busy filling gaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that the [Datastore reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807529/how-many-datastore-reads-consume-each-fetch-count-and-query-operations) is a crucial quota in our billing, I would like to read something about the "Datastore reads costs" since only the [write part](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html#Understanding_Write_Costs) is covered.